# javascript - How to store images on memory and load them from memory insteaId of cache?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, caching, memory

What I'm doing right now is using the following function to preload images to cache. I was wondering if it is possible to load them from memory for even faster load time.

```
function preloadImage (done, i) {
    if (!i) { i = 1; }

    var img = new Image();
    img.onloadend = function () {
        if (this.height == 0) { return done(); }
        preloadImage(done, i + 1);
    };
    img.src = "images/" + i;
}

preloadImage(function () { console.log('images loaded'); });
```

What I want to do is to load an array of `image()` elements with javascript and then show them in a slideshow.

Comment: You could try to use the localStorage.
In that example the localStorage is used to pass an image to the next page: you could try to use it for your needed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183180/how-to-save-an-image-to-localstorage-and-display-it-on-the-next-page

Comment: I want to use memory not disk.

Comment: Thanks for asking another question, and good luck with your image animation project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how to put an `Image` object directly into the DOM without having to reload with `src` after prefetching:

```js
// wait 2 seconds
setTimeout(() => {
  // preload image
  var image = new Image();

  image.addEventListener('load', function () {
    // place into DOM
    // assert(this === image);
    document.querySelector('img').replaceWith(this);
  });

  image.src = 'https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg';
}, 2000);
```

```html
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg"/>
```

Comment: This still isn't super helpful because he asked if you can load it from memory - this still requires another site as the source, and does not help if the image is loaded in from an API or a code-loaded zip file or whatnot. In this case you would be stuck writing everything to disk still to get a valid source path.

Comment: @Arcsector actually it doesn't require any of that. You can certainly create an `Image` instance from memory, but that's outside the scope of the question. The focus was on how to use the existing instance of the preloded `Image` directly, regardless of where it came from.